# Implement a file compression with Hadoop that the file already exists in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, compression, hdfs

How can I implement a file compression with Hadoop that the file already exists in HDFS?

I am programing a project, that require me to implement a inner compression in Hadoop. I have no idea about the implementation model. The concrete compression algorithm is not the important, and I just want the structure to compress a file use the map reduce that already exists in the HDFS.

Comment: So where are you having troubles? and the compression algorithm is pretty important if you are going to be distributing one file to many nodes for compression.

Comment: You want to compress files already in HDFS via a map reduce job - seems like a no reducer identity mapper job to me. You'll just need to configure your output format and the custom compressor